# Proper setup for universal OpenGL ES iPhone/iPad app in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, xcode4

I've been trying all morning to setup a univeral OpenGL-ES app with limited success. I can easily get the default OpenGL template app to compile for both devices and run just fine by adding a new XIB file and setting the proper values in it. Where I'm having trouble is figuring out how to give each device it's own unique GUI. Currently both devices use the same ViewController.xib file that is created with the project. How can I create a separate XIB file that uses the same ViewController .h and .m files? Do I need to create a separate AppDelegate class for each device type, or can they be shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach is to have a base AppDelegate class, and then subclass this for each device. Each delegate would then load its own XIB file with the correctly sized UIWindow and add the views.

Comment: I tried this as part of my experimenting this morning, but for some reason the iPad was the only device displaying correctly, if I ran the iPhone version, it would crash the app. Do you know of any sample OpenGL apps that show how you would set this up? The AppDelegate has an outlet for window and viewController, does each subclass AppDelegate need its own variable for each of these or can they be shared? If they can be shared, do I need a separate viewController object for each AppDelegate?